# Cocoapods/Eureka compile errors: linker command failed with exit 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, eureka-forms

I have an iOS project that I've been working on. The last thing I did was archive a working version of the app and upload to the app store.

I reopened the project for the first time since then and found that I can't compile the project, despite having made no changes.

I have tried: creating a new scheme for this target, adding the Eureka framework to "Link Binary with Libraries" in Build Phases, removing the Eureka framework and adding it again in Cocoapods.

I did recently change the product name, but was able to compile and archive the app after doing that.

Compile errors:

```
Ld /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParentNews.app/ParentNews normal x86_64
cd /Users/iMac2/Desktop/ParentNews
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Eureka -filelist /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Intermediates/ParentNews.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParentNews.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ParentNews.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework Eureka -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Intermediates/ParentNews.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParentNews.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ParentNews.swiftmodule -framework Pods_ParentNews -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Intermediates/ParentNews.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParentNews.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ParentNews_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ParentNews.app/ParentNews
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Eureka.framework/Eureka, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/iMac2/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParentNews-geljdkdldttkfccjdbidfttuyfho/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Eureka.framework/Eureka
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC6Eureka18FormViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.viewDidLoad () -> ()", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.viewWillAppear (Swift.Bool) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.prepareForSegue (__ObjC.UIStoryboardSegue, sender : Swift.AnyObject?) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.viewDidDisappear (Swift.Bool) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInputShouldClear <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> Swift.Bool", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInputShouldReturn <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> Swift.Bool", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.deleteAnimationForRows ([Eureka.BaseRow]) -> __C.UITableViewRowAnimation", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.insertAnimationForRows ([Eureka.BaseRow]) -> __C.UITableViewRowAnimation", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.reloadAnimationOldRows ([Eureka.BaseRow], newRows : [Eureka.BaseRow]) -> __C.UITableViewRowAnimation", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.rowValueHasBeenChanged (Eureka.BaseRow, oldValue : protocol<>?, newValue : protocol<>?) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInputDidEndEditing <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.inputAccessoryViewForRow (Eureka.BaseRow) -> __ObjC.UIView?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInputDidBeginEditing <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> ()", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInputShouldEndEditing <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> Swift.Bool", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.deleteAnimationForSections ([Eureka.Section]) -> __C.UITableViewRowAnimation", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.insertAnimationForSections ([Eureka.Section]) -> __C.UITableViewRowAnimation", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.reloadAnimationOldSections ([Eureka.Section], newSections : [Eureka.Section]) -> __C.UITableViewRowAnimation", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInputShouldBeginEditing <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> Swift.Bool", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.textInput <A where A: Swift.Equatable> (__ObjC.UITextInput, shouldChangeCharactersInRange : __C._NSRange, replacementString : Swift.String, cell : Eureka.Cell<A>) -> Swift.Bool", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.init (coder : __ObjC.NSCoder) -> Eureka.FormViewController?", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.init (coder : __ObjC.NSCoder) -> ParentNews.FilterController? in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.init (style : __C.UITableViewStyle) -> Eureka.FormViewController", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.init (style : __C.UITableViewStyle) -> ParentNews.FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.init (nibName : Swift.String?, bundle : __ObjC.NSBundle?) -> Eureka.FormViewController", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.init (nibName : Swift.String?, bundle : __ObjC.NSBundle?) -> ParentNews.FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.navigationOptions.getter : Eureka.RowNavigationOptions?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.navigationAccessoryView.getter : Eureka.NavigationAccessoryView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.form.getter : Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.tableView.getter : __ObjC.UITableView?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(oldBottomInset in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).getter : CoreGraphics.CGFloat?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(tableViewStyle in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).getter : __C.UITableViewStyle", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(_form in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).getter : Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.navigationOptions.materializeForSet : Eureka.RowNavigationOptions?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.form.materializeForSet : Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.tableView.materializeForSet : __ObjC.UITableView?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(oldBottomInset in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).materializeForSet : CoreGraphics.CGFloat?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(tableViewStyle in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).materializeForSet : __C.UITableViewStyle", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.navigationOptions.setter : Eureka.RowNavigationOptions?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.navigationAccessoryView.setter : Eureka.NavigationAccessoryView", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.form.setter : Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.tableView.setter : __ObjC.UITableView?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(oldBottomInset in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).setter : CoreGraphics.CGFloat?", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(tableViewStyle in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).setter : __C.UITableViewStyle", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.FormViewController.(_form in _1131D9CFD9D297ADC9C1EFB9DC530585).setter : Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"Eureka.Section.__allocating_init (Swift.String, (Eureka.Section) -> ()) -> Eureka.Section", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"(extension in Eureka):Eureka.RowType<A where A: Eureka.BaseRow, A: Eureka.RowType, A: Eureka.TypedRowType, A.Value == A.Cell.Value>.onChange ((A) -> ()) -> A", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"(extension in Eureka):Eureka.RowType<A where A: Eureka.BaseRow, A: Eureka.RowType, A: Eureka.TypedRowType, A.Value == A.Cell.Value>.init (Swift.String?, (A) -> ()) -> A", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"Eureka.Section.(init (Swift.String, (Eureka.Section) -> ()) -> Eureka.Section).(default argument 1)", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"(extension in Eureka):Eureka.RowType<A where A: Eureka.BaseRow, A: Eureka.RowType, A: Eureka.TypedRowType, A.Value == A.Cell.Value>.(init (Swift.String?, (A) -> ()) -> A).(default argument 0)", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"type metadata for Eureka.FormViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ParentNews16FilterController in FilterController.o
"type metadata accessor for Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
  type metadata accessor for Swift.IndexingGenerator<Eureka.Form> in FilterController.o
  type metadata accessor for Swift.MutableSlice<Eureka.Form> in FilterController.o
"type metadata accessor for Eureka.Section", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
  type metadata accessor for Swift.IndexingGenerator<Eureka.Form> in FilterController.o
  type metadata accessor for Swift.MutableSlice<Eureka.Form> in FilterController.o
  type metadata accessor for Swift.IndexingGenerator<Swift.MutableSlice<Eureka.Form>> in FilterController.o
"type metadata accessor for Eureka.CheckRow", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
  lazy protocol witness table accessor for type Eureka.CheckRow and conformance <A, B where B: Eureka.BaseCell, B: Eureka.CellType, B: Eureka.TypedCellType, A == B.Value> Eureka.Row<A, B> : Eureka.TypedRowType in Eureka in FilterController.o
"type metadata accessor for Eureka.CheckCell", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
  lazy protocol witness table accessor for type Eureka.CheckCell and conformance <A where A: Swift.Equatable> Eureka.Cell<A> : Eureka.TypedCellType in Eureka in FilterController.o
"protocol witness table for Eureka.Form : Swift.CollectionType in Eureka", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"protocol witness table for Eureka.Form : Swift.MutableIndexable in Eureka", referenced from:
  type metadata accessor for Swift.MutableSlice<Eureka.Form> in FilterController.o
"protocol witness table for Eureka.Form : Swift.Indexable in Eureka", referenced from:
  type metadata accessor for Swift.IndexingGenerator<Eureka.Form> in FilterController.o
"protocol witness table for Eureka.CheckRow : Eureka.RowType in Eureka", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"protocol witness table accessor for <A, B where B: Eureka.BaseCell, B: Eureka.CellType, B: Eureka.TypedCellType, A == B.Value> Eureka.Row<A, B> : Eureka.TypedRowType in Eureka", referenced from:
  lazy protocol witness table accessor for type Eureka.CheckRow and conformance <A, B where B: Eureka.BaseCell, B: Eureka.CellType, B: Eureka.TypedCellType, A == B.Value> Eureka.Row<A, B> : Eureka.TypedRowType in Eureka in FilterController.o
"protocol witness table accessor for <A where A: Swift.Equatable> Eureka.Cell<A> : Eureka.TypedCellType in Eureka", referenced from:
  lazy protocol witness table accessor for type Eureka.CheckCell and conformance <A where A: Swift.Equatable> Eureka.Cell<A> : Eureka.TypedCellType in Eureka in FilterController.o
"static Eureka.<<< infix (Eureka.Section, Eureka.BaseRow) -> Eureka.Section", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
"static Eureka.+++ infix (Eureka.Form, Eureka.Section) -> Eureka.Form", referenced from:
  ParentNews.FilterController.viewDidLoad () -> () in FilterController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below things.

(1) Any framework or .a is missing in project. ( When it is being added 1st time in project, may be it is not copied in project folder, so when you archive and un archive somewhere else, it is not getting reference from location) )

(2) Framework search path - add below line.

$(PROJECT_DIR)/ProjectName/WhichEverIsYourFrameWork  (Path upto .a file )

(3) Delete that framework, delete framework search path, now just simply drag and drop it in root, framework search file will create automatically.

**Addition**

(4) When you change location where cocoapods were installed then you have to fire command again at new location to install command again.
Clean and Build it.

Comment: is this advice relevent for cocoapods? I can't find Eureka.framework in my project. could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes, check addition in my answer.